# hyperledger-fabric setup issue

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Please, I need some assistance while setting up hyperledger-fabric

I am stuck in the final step of the tutorial, in the following image the stack trace and details, see error message:

"Connection is not in READY state"

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Node 10 isn't supported as of now. You need to use Node 8. I see you are using nvm so first do `nvm install 8`, and re-install the composer packages. Also don't use `sudo` invoke the commands or run node.

Comment: @david_k please help again! I spent a lot of time in a new issue:  "Connection is not in READY state" https://imgur.com/a/sDKr4Ll

Answer (score 0):

The error *Connection is not in READY state* has been seen several time due to a problem with a particular version of grpc.  The problem is covered in detail in [this issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3944)

If you uninstall and re-install composer-cli the problem should be resolved for you.